# How can I find out which package installed a particular executable?

Tags: debian, package-management

For example, on Debian or Ubuntu, which package has the `/sbin/shutdown` command in it? I want to read the source of that command (and possibly modify it to report notification on desktop) and I didn't know which package source to download.